# jquery-rails producing old jquery version

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I am using rails 3.2.2, jquery-rails 2.0.3, with asset pipeline enabled. For some reason, require jquery is producing jQuery 1.7.2 in my application.js file. I would like to use the latest 1.9.1.  I made sure jquery-rails is up to date.  There are lots of posts about using older versions, but can someone explain why I wouldn't get the newest version?

Comment: Are you sure your Gemfile doesn't have a version-specific entry and that the Gemfile.lock isn't referencing an old version? I'd run `bundle update` to make sure I have/am using the latest gems.

Comment: Rails uses an older version of Jquery by default - could this be the problem?

Comment: Rails uses the older version to provide support for every type of devise - I think you can upgrade it manually, although there was talk about this on the Rails Github repo

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the `'jquery-rails-cdn'` gem instead? It could solve your problem and it is a better approach.

https://github.com/kenn/jquery-rails-cdn